# How does apk's replaces work when the package being replaced gets upgraded?

Tags: package-management, packaging, alpine-linux, apk-tools

Say I have a package A, and package B. Package B contains some files which deliberately conflict with package A, and it is desirable for package B's files to be favoured over the ones in package A if a user installs both. The easy solution to this with apk-tools is to have package B include `replaces=A` in its `APKBUILD` so that the resulting package contains this metadata.

Given this, if package A is installed and then B, B's conflicting files should take precedent. However, what happens if package A then gets upgraded and B doesn't? Do the conflicting files from A take precedent, or does apk keep the ones from B?

Comment: I do not think B conflicting files should take precedence. In fact I do not think B should ever be installed. Package A may misbehave with a new version of the conflicting file. A big NO. In Debian usually only the same source package may do that (so updated at same time), or it requires coordination between packages (and maybe using "alternative"/symlinks/etc. to have a smooth transition.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I don't understand the relevance of your comment. I'm trying to understand how apk-tools works. How is what Debian does related to that?

Comment: It is a comment, not an answer, but similar problem, similar solutions (people talk and discuss and read how things were done on other distribution). And many package managers took "inspiration" on dpkg. Reading much of alpine doc, I think the inspiration is real

Comment: In any case, https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/APKBUILD_Reference#replaces will help

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes, I have read that, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Mu interpretation "The files from this package will override" is about package, not the time of installation of such package, so for me a new A should not override. In any case you have the next option to better control. And you should also do real test: never rely on documentations (especially on corner cases)